# What does it mean when a test passes silently?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

So I'm in this computer science class and most of our assignments have this line saying, "Your test should pass silently." I am unsure what this means because I feel like I wouldn't know if the test was even working at the first place. Can you guys help to clarify this for me?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not asking your instructor this question? They would be in the best position to explain what is meant, wouldn't they?

Comment: Seriously: do **not** get into the habit of asking *other* people first. One important aspect of **learning** is the ability to **ask** person X when person X says something you don't understand. Worst case, talk to him after the lesson. But learn to ask directly. Believe me: that is a **very** important skill to have.

Comment: He gave something vague when I first asked him about it. I thought it was a general term used in the industry, and the thought of asking him first again didn't cross my mind. Thanks for the advice guys.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to ask your instructor, but my interpretation would be:

"If this test fails, it should announce that (by throwing an error, for example). If this test passes, it shouldn't announce anything. No news is good news."

To verify that your tests work, you could always make a "noisier" test while you're coding/debugging, for example one that displays its result to the console. Just remember to make it silent before you turn in the assignment.